# My php script isn't visible in the browser

Tags: php, html

I just started PHP I got my XAMMP server up and running and now I made my first html test page and added one line of PHP script but it isn't showing in my browser.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
    <title>Mijn php-script</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    phpinfo();
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

It does however shows the title I gave it, can anybody tell me why the rest isn't showing? it should show the info version page of my PHP.

Comment: Does it output the php-source as is?

Comment: Yes if I click the right mouse button and go to the source of the page it shows me my code

Comment: you're running this off of your own computer? if so, how? @JeroenSomers

Comment: @JeroenSomers you will need to take it up with the answer below. I can't keep looking at the question/comments to see an update/replies; good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You need to save your file as .PHP and not as .HTML in order to be able to run this. Also, you need to fix the HTML closing tag in the end, as you are closing the HEAD again.

Comment: Yes, change the bottom line from `</head>` to `</html>`

Comment: I did save it as a .php file
I fixed the HTML closing tag in the end and deleted the second HEAD closing tag.

Still it doesn't work

Comment: Give us a screenshot so we can see what you see. Because this code you posted with the corrections I suggested works fine. UNLESS, your Apache hasn't started. Check XAMPP's Apache indication.

Comment: I'm updating my apache as we speak, I had a very old version which was running fine but we live in 2017 now, keep you posted on the progress.

Comment: Although true; one can instruct their system to treat `.html` files as php. Edit (ping) @DimitrisDamilos seeing your comment below, I take it that was for me. You should have pinged me directly.

Comment: True. But he said "I made my first html test page" and I assumed there was no way he could have edited his .htaccess/Apache config to do that.

Comment: it's fixed, I opened it locally instead of through htdocs from XAMPP
Now my php file is in the HTDOCS folder from xampp and it works

Comment: Happy to hear that. Please mark this Answer as correct if it was. :)